# Wifi enabling my Arduino

Tags: arduino, wifi

I'm having a lot of trouble finding wifi enabled arduino shields. All the places I've seen them are out of stock for some reason.

Would this thing work? How would I hook it up?

http://www.rovingnetworks.com/wifly-gsx.php

Basically I want to build a network enabled (wireless) robot with the arduino. So you can see it's clearly better if I can get a wifi shield.

**Edit:** To follow up on this post, I did end up getting the Wifly shield from Sparkfun. I was unable to get it working with the Arduino (Duemilanove) I had, and I ordered an Uno on a hunch, and it works on that! Connects to APs and can host an ad-hoc network. Unfortunately no security options exist for ad-hoc. But I'm okay with that.

Comment: You can check the answers to my question as well: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/10596/is-there-another-arduino-ethernet-module-besides-the-arduino-ethernet-shield

Comment: Here is a great blog entry on how to connect a low cost WiFi router to an Arduino:
http://todbot.com/blog/2010/12/16/wifi-for-arduino-with-asus-wl-520gu/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These modules are the basis of most WiFi shields for Arduino.  If you are reasonably comfortable with your soldering ability, you could dead bug a module like this without too much difficulty.  Just connect all the powers and grounds properly, and bring TX/RX to your Arduino.

That said, if you dig a little deeper, you'll find the shields in stock at vendors like SparkFun, Futurlec, Adafruit, etc.  If one vendor is out of stock, others will have it.

If you're just looking at using WiFi for remote control, another option might be ZigBee.  WiFi might be a little overkill for simple remote control, unless you really want the novelty of controlling the thing through the web.

Comment: I accepted this answer because it was the most helpful. I think I'm going to get the Wifly shield from Sparkfun since it's my only option at the moment. I can't wait an indefinite amount of time to see what happened to asynclabs' wifi solutions just to save $30...

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how comfortable you feel with Linux, a really cheep option can be to use a cheep wi-fi router (such as a La Fonera) wit a custom firmware installed.  a google search for "Arduino Fon" will give you some examples.
Jim

Answer (score 2):

Here is the later version of the [WiFly Shield](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/9954) - US $70.

Comment: I would rather go with the asynclabs solutions which are cheaper and don't require me to buy additional stackable headers... I suppose this is my only option now, though. It just doesnt look like its worth $90.

Comment: Async Labs out of business - see http://www.asynclabs.com/home

Answer (score 1):

Watterott sells a nice Wifi shield called "WiFly Shield" its about 80€, get it here: http://www.watterott.com/de/Arduino-WiFly-Shield i looked for it on the sparkfun page, but it says deprecated. Watterott ships internationally so you could order there, eventhough its here in Germany. I hope i could help.